# Find $x$ for a given derivative value.

Tags: numerical-methods

Given a function $ y=f(x)$. I know that the function is continuous, now for a given $y^{'}_0$, I have to find $x$ such that $\dfrac{\mathrm df(x)}{\mathrm dx} = \dfrac{dy}{dx}=y_0^{'}$ at that $x$.

To solve this problem numerically i tried

$g(x) = \frac {f(x+h) - f(x-h)}{2h} - y_0^{'} = 0$

so $f(x+h) - f(x-h) = 2h \cdot y_0^{'} $

but this is not and an efficient method since it depends a lot on choice of $h$ and I have to solve it multiple times..

Is there a better way?

Comment: Hi and welcome to our community! Please try to typeset your posts using MathJax.

Comment: A continuous function is not necessarily differentiable. Moreover, without more information about $f$, trying to find $x$ such that $\frac{df}{dx}(x)=y_0$ is almost an impossible task...

Comment: f is differentiable. and also i have to solve it numerically

Comment: What is the function exactly?

Comment: function is something like

Comment: Used prime for denoting  given  derivative value as convention and edited. Switched to a simpler example. Hope alright.

Answer (score 1):

If $y(x)=f(x)= x^2/4 +5,\, y_0^{'}=1.1 $ are given then by direct differentiation:

$$ y'(x_0)=x_0/2 = y_0^{'}=1.1 \rightarrow x_0= 2.2 $$

which can be solved numerically.

Comment: No, But we are certain that the df/dx takes the value y0 at some x

Comment: Can you use Runge-Kutta numerical methods to solve for $y'(x)= yo?$

Comment: In my case the function cannot be directly differentiated. the differentiation is calculated numerically. this whole problem I have to solve numerically.

Comment: In reply to IsaacRen you stated that $f$ is differentiable.